# Windows Server 2008 Standard vs. Web

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I'm currently comparing Windows Server 2008 versions to see what to use.

What i found is this, that might affect me:

- RAM: 32GB. (the same)
- Sockets: 4 (the same)
- Remote Desktop: 2 (the same)
- IIS: true (the same)
- Application Server: Only standard.

I will run my server as a single CPU (4 core) 8GB RAM, 2x raid1 web-server running:

- IIS
- Asp.net
- .Net 4
- Third part mail server. (Only for sending mail from my web-application)
- SQL Server Express (My data is not more then 10 GB)
- Some minor applications for import and export of data.

I might use external load balancer if I install a second machine in the future.

My question is if you see any reason for me to go for standard that is 4 x price compared to web.

Answer (score 2):

One word: no. Web is specifically done for running websites and has other advantages possibly (licensing users accessing the website for example is not needed for web edition, sometimes for standard, depending what parts of windows the website accesses.

Comment: In adition - third aprty mail server for SENDING? WHat for ;) SMTP service is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Standard edition here. I have a similar setup using Web Edition and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are some hardware limitations in using Windows Server Web vs. Standard.  From what you've written here, it sounds like these might apply:

Limit of 32 GB RAM
Limit of 4 CPU sockets

Generally, web edition limits 'Windows' services that you might want to install (AD server is the big gotcha for many enterprise clients -- limits LDAP authentication, if required).

You can check out a list of the 2008 server editions and which ones have which rights and privileges for hardware and services, direct from [Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/C/6/FC6006B5-866E-42C1-88F8-9AC4B8BC610D/WS%20Brand%20Pages%20-%20Editions%20Comparison%20Guide.pdf).